# Extension for Python

Tags: python

It is written in a documentation:

> Such extension modules can do two things that can’t be done directly
>   in Python: they can implement new built-in object types, and they can
>   call C library functions **and system calls**.

### Syscalls

I cannot see why "system calls" are special here. I know what it is syscall. I didn't see why it is special and why it cannot be done directly in Python.
Especially, we can use `open` in Python to open a file. It must be a underlying syscall to get descriptor for file ( in Unix systems).

It was just `open`. Besides that we can use: `call(["ls", "-l"])` and it also must use syscall like `execve` or something like that.

### Functions

Why is calling C library function is special? After all:

> ctypes is a foreign function library for Python. It provides C
>   compatible data types, and allows **calling functions in DLLs or shared
>   libraries**. It can be used to wrap these libraries in pure Python.

Answer (score -1):

Essentially system calls interact with the underlying system services(that is the Kernel for Linux). C functions on the other hand run on user space exclusively. To that sense system call is more "special".

Comment: You don't understand what I am asking for.